# How can I hook any event/command from Emacs frame?

Tags: emacs, lisp, frame

- frame position changed
- frame size changed
- frame 'set as input foucus'

Answer (score 1):

Some of that is described under [Input Events](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Events.html#Input-Events) (at least the focus event).

Comment: I tried on my Snow Leopard, but only 'switch-frame', also not effect any time. Do I hook the event correctly - `(global-set-key [switch-frame] 'foo)`?

Comment: I found that the best way to hook event is `defadvice'. Thanks all the same.